# Number of solutions to $x+2y+3z=100$ ($x,y,z\in\Bbb N$)

Tags: combinatorics, diophantine-equations

> How many solutions are there to $$x+2y+3z=100$$ with $x,y,z\in\Bbb N$?

Can anyone tell me how to do it? I've got no idea how to start.

Comment: hint choose z, then choose y such that $2y+3z<100$, then determine x from your equation

Comment: Does $0 \in \mathbb N$ ?

Comment: Compute the coefficient of $w^{100}$ in the Taylor series of $$\frac{1}{(1-w)(1-w^2)(1-w^3)}$$ around $w=0$, through partial fraction decomposition. You will get that the answer is $\color{red}{884}$ and that there are roughly $\frac{(N+3)^2}{12}$ natural solutions of $x+2y+3z=N$.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1529121/the-number-pn-of-triplets-x-y-z-x2y3z-n

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio - hmm, I get that *884* nicely with a one-liner in Pari/GP using your recipe. However, if I follow Shai Horowitz' brute force recipe I cannot produce that *848* by whatever seeming meningful. However, for the number of $z,y$-combinations only I get *748* and for the overall sum $C$ of possible combinations $(x,y,z)$ I get $C=25736$. Something that I'm missing?

Comment: @GottfriedHelms: me and Shai are making different assumptions about $0\in\mathbb{N}$, the discrepancy lies in that.

Comment: @Jack : ah, I see. I've included that variant in my answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counting bounded integer solutions to $\sum_ia_ix_i\leqq n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/910809/counting-bounded-integer-solutions-to-sum-ia-ix-i-leqq-n)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

If $z\geq 33$, there is no solution.

If $z=32$, then you can set $y=1$ and you must then set $x=2$.

If $z=31$, you need $x+2y=7$, so you get $y=1$ or $y=2$ or $y=3$.

If $z=30$, you can have $y=1,2,3,4$

If $z=29$, you can have $y=1,2,3,4,5,6$

---

Can you write a pattern? How many options are there for odd values of $z$? How many for even values of $z$?

---

*Remark:*

If you consider $0\in\mathbb N$, the solution changes, but the basic idea remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Let's denote the limiting value in your question  as $V=100$ and let's assume $x,y,z>0$ (so $ \small  0 \not \in \Bbb N$).

Checking using brute force some smaller $V$, all divisible by $\small 6$, give a polynomially interpolatable sequence of values, producing the interpolating polynomial:
$$ P(x)= (2 x^3 -15 x^2+30 x)/72 $$

For values $V$, which are not divisible by $6$ we get a fractional residue , actually
$$\small  \{P(6k ) \} = 0 \qquad \qquad  \{P(6k+1 )\} = 17/72 \qquad  \{P(6k+2 ) \} = 16/72 \\ \small 
 \{P(6k+3 ) \} =  9/72 \qquad  \{P(6k+4 ) \} =  8/72 \qquad  \{P(6k+5 ) \} = 25/72 
$$

The function
$$ C(x) = \lfloor P(x) \rfloor =  \left \lfloor {2 x^3 - 15 x^2+ 30 x\over 72} \right \rfloor $$
gives correct values for all *x*, for instance $V=100$ we get $C(V)= 25736$ , and for $V=12$ we get $C(V)=23$ (which can be checked by hand).

---

If we assume $x,y,z \ge 0$ (thus allow $ 0 \in \Bbb N$  ) we get the slightly changed function
$$ C_0(x)= \left \lfloor { 2 x^3 + 21 x^2 + 66 x + 72 \over 72} \right \rfloor $$

and get $C_0(100) =  30787$